# replace string in a text file with the occurence of string

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, gsub

I am trying to form a long index file of the format:

```
[1]
13 14 15 16 17 18
[2]
89 90 91 92 93 94
[3]
165 166 167 168 169 170
[4]
---------------------
```

and I have the file in the format:

```
[index-i]
13 14 15 16 17 18
[index-i]
89 90 91 92 93 94
[index-i]
165 166 167 168 169 170
[index-i]
-------
```

How to replace 'index-i' in the brackets with its 'occurrence'  using a script

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do edit your samples in code tags as its not clear as of now. Also please do add your efforts in your question and let us know then.

Comment: So, the former data set is the expected output and the latter is the sample data? You must've tried something?

Comment: @Pragati: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "with its 'occurrence' " ?

Answer (score 1):

If longindex contains your input file

```
$ cat longindex 
[index-i]
13 14 15 16 17 18
[index-i]
89 90 91 92 93 94
[index-i]
165 166 167 168 169 170
[index-i]
```

then with awk (or gawk) you could use

```
$ gawk '/^\[/{print "[" ++i "]"; next;} {print}' longindex 
[1]
13 14 15 16 17 18
[2]
89 90 91 92 93 94
[3]
165 166 167 168 169 170
[4]
```

Comment: `^1` and can be abbreviated to `awk '/^\[/{$0="["(++i)"]"} 1'`. You should always add the parens when concatenating with `++number` to ensure which side of the concatenation awk applies the `++` to otherwise it COULD read `"[" ++i` as `("["++) i` instead of what you wanted, `"[" (++i)`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed '/^\[/{g;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;h;s/.*/[&]/}' file
```

If the current line start with an open square bracket process the line as follows.

Replace the current line by the contents of the hold space.

Increment the counter.

Update the hold space.

Surround with square brackets.